# Getting the first fold in sklearn.cross_validation.KFold without looping

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When creating a K-Folds cross validation iterator in scikit-learn, how can I get the first fold?

Example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
np.random.seed(seed=1) # for reproducibility

X = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
kf = KFold(4, n_folds=2)
```

I can get the first fold using:

```
for idx, fold in enumerate(kf): 
    break

print('The fold {0} is {1}'.format(idx, fold))
```

output:

```
The fold 0 is (array([2, 3]), array([0, 1]))
```

But I'd like to get the first fold without having to do a loop (there should be some easier way that I missed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first convert the `KFold` object to an iterator and then use once the `next` method:

```
>>> next(iter(kf))
(array([2, 3]), array([0, 1]))
```